# Does using SafeMath for uint is herited from child contract

Tags: solidity, safemath

I have this code:

```
contract A {
    using SafeMath for uint;
    ...
}

contract B is A {
    ...
}
```

Does my contract B herits from "using SafeMath for uint;"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to declare library usage for every contract explicitly.

In case of SafeMath, you don't have to use it, if you use solidity 0.8.0 and after. Overflow/underflow checks are included in that versions. See https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/080-breaking-changes.html :

> Arithmetic operations revert on underflow and overflow. You can use unchecked { ... } to use the previous wrapping behaviour.
>
> Checks for overflow are very common, so we made them the default to increase readability of code, even if it comes at a slight increase of gas costs.